# Is there a way to exclude a string if it begins with some values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way I can check if any a value starts with any value in an array?

```
var value = "background-color";
var value2 = "--my-variable";

var excludeItems = ["--", "-", "_"];

if (does value starts with excludeItems) {
    // then exclude
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `.some` of the items in the array pass a `startsWith` test on the string:

```js
var value1 = "background-color";
var value2 = "--my-variable";

var excludeItems = ["--", "-", "_"];

const v1excluded = excludeItems.some(str => value1.startsWith(str));
const v2excluded = excludeItems.some(str => value2.startsWith(str));

console.log(v1excluded, v2excluded);
```

In this particular case, because a string that starts with `--` will also necessarily start with `-`, you can leave the `--` out of the `excludeItems` array entirely, if you wanted.

If `excludeItems` is static, and you have many characters to test, you might be able to do it more concisely with a regular expression and a character set:

```js
var value1 = "background-color";
var value2 = "--my-variable";

const excludeItems = /^[-_!@#$%]/;

const v1excluded = excludeItems.test(value1);
const v2excluded = excludeItems.test(value2);

console.log(v1excluded, v2excluded);
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with CertainPerformance's answer you can also have a oneliner as something like, `[value1, value2].filter(val => excludeItems.some(str => val.startsWith(str)))`

```js
var value1 = "background-color";
var value2 = "--my-variable";

var excludeItems = ["--", "-", "_"];

const excluded = [value1, value2].filter(val => excludeItems.some(str => val.startsWith(str)));

const included = [value1, value2].filter(val => !excludeItems.some(str => val.startsWith(str)));

console.log(excluded);
console.log(included);
```